# Select a table when table name has been stored as a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, select

Using MYSQL, how can I select a table whose name has been stored as a variable? For instance, I have 2 tables (T1 and T2) and I want to derive T3:

```
DECLARE i INT; DECLARE n INT;
DECLARE o VARCHAR(50);    
DECLARE T3 VARCHAR(50);

SET n=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `T1`);
i=1
WHILE i<n+1 DO
SET o=(SELECT customer FROM `T1` WHERE IDligne=i); 
SET T3=(SELECT MiddleCat FROM `T2` WHERE customer=o); 
SET x = SELECT * FROM `T3`; 

SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
END
```

I want to set the variable (x) to be equal to the result of the `T3` query (to retrieve the name of other tables):

But this shows an error. What query should I used instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a prepared statement.  You can use a session variable to store the result of your query.  In the example below, I assign the result of a count query into a variable `@result`.

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(50);
SET @result := 0;
SET T3 = (SELECT MiddleCat FROM `T2` WHERE customer=o);
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @result FROM ', T3);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Highly relevant: [Using select into local variable and prepared statement in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917345/using-select-into-local-variable-and-prepared-statement-in-mysql/7925914)

Comment: But how can I use the outcome of this prepared statement further in my procedure. For instance as new variable?

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria One option would be to select the result of your query into a user variable, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Simply in your case you can user either of the following :*

```
 1. Print T3 
 2. Select T3
```